# axes are not displayed with add_axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

The code is executing and even showing the graph, but am not able to view the x axis and y axis. The legends are showing but not the axis, I have tried adjusting the dpi but it was of no help. I am using vscode

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
langs = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'PHP']
students = [23,17,35,29,12]
ax.bar(langs, students)
plt.ylim(0,35)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_axes([0,0,1,1])` makes the axes position from the bottom left point on the canvas, thus causes the axes to be outside the canvas of the figure. You can remove `add_axes` and try `plt.bar(langs,students)` instead.
The full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig = plt.figure()
langs = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'PHP']
students = [23,17,35,29,12]
plt.bar(langs, students)
plt.ylim(0,35)
plt.show()
```

And the figure

[image]

Or if you want to use `ax` so bad you can use `fig, ax = plt.figure()`

Comment: You could also change your axes to something else, like `ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])`. When you save your figure you can also use `bbox_inches = 'tight'` and it will show the minimum size that contains everything, even if that includes things off the canvas from [0,0,1,1].